# How to write a text file in C#

Tags: c#, text, new-operator

I need to write a strings into a text file from C#, each string on a new line...How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append lines to a file using a StreamWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx):

```
string[] mystrings = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Qux" };

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt", mystrings);
```

Comment: +1; can't beat a one-liner! Exception handling not included. Available in .NET 2.0+. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to append the text lines to the file, use [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx):

```
string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about StreamWriter class? Read more [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And do not forget about exception handling e.g missing file permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `StreamWriter` class; take a look at [this](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx) tutorial.  A new line is simply the character `\n` (Unix) or the characters `\r\n` (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this sample into your code:

```
string myText = "This is my string";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Jack\source\repos\My Text.txt", myText);
```