# Append lines to a file using a StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want to append lines to my file. I am using a StreamWriter:

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt");
file2.WriteLine(someString);
file2.Close();
```

The output of my file should be several strings below each other, but I have only one row, which is overwritten every time I run this code.

Is there some way to let the StreamWriter append to an existing file?

Comment: Don't forget to dispose `StreamWriter` . A `using` block is better syntax for this.

Comment: This is also why I prefer not to worry about streams when doing very quick updates to a file by using File.AppendAllText - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

Comment: @TheCodeKing - Can you show me some code to do that ?

Comment: @blasto `using (var stream = new StreamWriter(..)) { stream.WriteLine(..); }`

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", true);
```

With this overload of the StreamWriter constructor you choose if you append the file, or overwrite it.

C# 4 and above offers the following syntax, which some find more readable:

```
new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", append: true);
```

Comment: Append works great.  For my purposes I needed to add a header row (1st line in the file) if the file doesn't exist.  If you need to know if the file was newly created (no data), you can test for swObject.BaseStream.Position=0.

Answer (score 157):

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
 {
    sw.WriteLine(something);
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

I assume you are executing *all* of the above code each time you write something to the file. Each time the stream for the file is opened, its seek pointer is positioned at the beginning so all writes end up overwriting what was there before.

You can solve the problem in two ways: either with the convenient

```
file2 = new StreamWriter("c:/file.txt", true);
```

or by explicitly repositioning the stream pointer yourself:

```
file2 = new StreamWriter("c:/file.txt");
file2.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

Comment: what if the file has 10mb and I start writing from position 0, but only 10kb, how can I assure that the file *only* contains the 10kb data I've just written?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt", true);
file2.WriteLine(someString);
file2.Close();
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace this:

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("c:/file.txt");
```

with this:

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("c:/file.txt", true);
```

`true` indicates that it appends text.

Answer (score 7):

Actually only Jon's answer (Sep 5 '11 at 9:37) with BaseStream.Seek worked for my case. Thanks Jon! I needed to **append** lines to a zip archived txt file.

```
using (FileStream zipFS = new FileStream(@"c:\Temp\SFImport\test.zip",FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (ZipArchive arch = new ZipArchive(zipFS,ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = arch.GetEntry("testfile.txt");
        if (entry == null)
        {
            entry = arch.CreateEntry("testfile.txt");
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine("text content");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `FileStream` before using a `StreamWriter` and specify options for appending. Then there is no need to `.Seek()` because the content will be appended at the end of the file.

Answer (score 5):

Use [this `StreamWriter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) with 2nd parameter - `true`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is using [System.IO.File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx)

This is equivalent to the StreamWriter overloads others have given.

Also [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) may give a slightly easier interface without having to worry about opening and closing the stream. Though you may need to then worry about putting in your own linebreaks. :)

Answer (score 3):

One more simple way is using the `File.AppendText` it appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist and returns a `System.IO.StreamWriter`

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(logFilePath + "log.txt"))
{                                                
    sw.WriteLine("this is a log");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:/file.txt");
```

with this code:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("c:/file.txt");
```

and then write your line to the text file like this:

```
sw.WriteLine("text content");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =new System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath,true))
             {
                    
                    
            `file.Write("SOme Text TO Write" + Environment.NewLine);         
                    
             }
```