# How Can I get File Directory with FileName?

Tags: c#

How Can I get File Directory with name from `SaveFileDialog`?

I tried this:

```
string directory = File.GetFileDirectory with name ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the directory from the dialog's `FileName` property.

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDialog.ShowDialog();
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveDialog.FileName);
```

Comment: string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
label12.Text = fileDirectory;

I tried it but doesn't work :(

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: Path is not valid. If u want I can take ScreenShot ?

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.IO;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Take a screenshot, also show what `saveDialog.FileName` is.

Comment: string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName); --> this line

Comment: When the error happens, try hovering over "FileName" and see what it says.

Comment: As soon as the error occurs, click "Immediate Window" and type `saveFileDialog1.FileName` and tell me the result.

Comment: Why is it "null" ? I think I can't save the file ? Am I right ?

Comment: I need to create text file with SaveFileDialog and I need this file's directory . . .

Comment: Are you hitting cancel by chance? You need to make sure you type in a name and click save. The code works fine on my machine.

Comment: can u send me an e-mail please ? For teamviever ? Is that possible ?
or add me skype : omur.c. is my username.
omurcanumutyurdugul@gmail.com

Comment: I found your error, you are using `saveFileDialog1.FileName` when you should be using your newly created `save.FileName`

Comment: It worked but Text file not created. :( I have a directory but not textFile

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM :) Path.GetFullPath is worked. :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You will need to do your own saving, as it only provides a dialog. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854984/append-text-using-streamwriter