# How to save what is typed in console to a text file?

Tags: c#, console-application

Is it possible to save what is typed in the console to a text file?

I know how to write and read from a text file, but I would like to know how to save what is typed in console itself to a text file.

So opening a console, typing text in the console itself (the black console screen), pressing Enter (or something else), and saving it to a file.

I haven't found any answers that work so I'm beginning to think it isn't possible.

On a side note; is there another name for that console application window? Or is it actually called console application window?

Comment: Is it an external console application or yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't found any answers that work so I'm beginning to think it isn't possible.

What were you searching on? [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string`, which is easily [appended to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/c-sharp-append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter):

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("ConsoleOutput.txt", append: true))
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Not all problems are solved on the web exactly as you require; break it up in smaller parts (*"get string from console", "write string to file"*) and you *will* find the solution specific to your situation.

---

If this is about reading output from another process, this is a duplicate of [How to spawn a process and capture its STDOUT in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. As usual, the answer was more obvious than I realised. Thank you to everyone else for the fast replies and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches:

1. Just use [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this in loop until some specific symbol. At the same time adding lines to a file stream.
2. Another elegant solution to use [`Console.SetOUt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Take a look on second example from **MSDN**. Pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to redirect console output to a text file with name `consoleOut.txt`

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("consoleOut.txt", FileMode.Create);
var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is no external console window, you can use Console.ReadLine() to get the typed string and save it to a file by calling e.g. File.WriteAllText, StreamWriter,...