# Appendtext not working

Tags: c#, filestream

So I'm trying to make a program that calculates and saves your BMI into a file.
I tried using `appendtext` like this.

```
StreamWriter logboekBMI = new StreamWriter(path + "Logbmi.txt");
logboekBSA.Close();

logboekBMI = File.AppendText(path + "Logbmi.txt");
logboekBMI.WriteLine("BMI: " + bmi.getBMI());
logboekBMI.Close();
```

And I read the file to a text box like this:

```
StreamReader logbmi = new StreamReader(path + "Logbmi.txt");
txtLogboek.Text = logbmi.ReadToEnd();
```

It deletes the line that was already in the file and inserts the new one. It never appends.

Comment: This code doesn't work at all, where have you copied it from? All you need is the one line `File.AppendAllText("C:\path\to\file\Logbmi.txt", "The text to add");`

Comment: Forgot to say then you just need `File.ReadAllText("C:\path\to\file\Logbmi.txt");` to get it back again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append lines to a file using a StreamWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to write text to a file without overwriting any text that is already there.

In that case, you need to define your `StreamWriter` like so:

```
StreamWriter logboekBMI = new StreamWriter(path + "Logbmi.txt", true);
```

The `true` parameter means that you want to append text to the file. Without it, you are overwriting the file every time you create a new `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems over complicated for what you want to do. You only need two lines of code, one to save the text and one to read it.

Save text: [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

```
File.AppendAllText("C:\path\to\file\Logbmi.txt", "The BMI to add");
```

Read text: [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string, and then closes the file.

```
txtLogboek.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\path\to\file\Logbmi.txt");
```