# Comparing Arrays while using substrings

Tags: c#, arrays

#### Removing part of an array

So currently I have the following code

```
public static void ReadSuburbs()
{
    String directory = @"C:\Address Sorting\";
    string[] linesA = new string[5] 
    { 
        "41 Boundary Rd", 
        "93 Boswell Terrace", 
        "4/100 Lockrose St", 
        "32 Williams Ave", 
        "27 scribbly gum st sunnybank hills"
    };

    int found = 0;
    foreach (string s in linesA)
    {
        found = s.IndexOf("st");
        Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(found + 3));
    }
}
```

Currently I get the following result

> Boundary Rd
>   Boswell Terrace
>   100 Lockrose St
>   Williams Ave
>   sunnybank hills

I was wondering if there was a way that I could, instead of removing characters, remove the first three words. For example if I have an array

```
string[] linesA = new string[5] 
{ 
    "41 Boundary Rd", 
    "93 Boswell Terrace", 
    "4/100 Lockrose St", 
    "32 Williams Ave", 
    "27 scribbly gum st sunnybank hills"
};
```

I want to remove every first three words in this array which will leave me with this as a result if i print to console.

> st sunnybank hills

Comment: But "st sunnybank hills" isn't "every 3rd word in this array;" it's the last three words in the last item in the array.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, what you want is to remove the first three words and not every 3rd word:

```
string[] linesA = new string[5] { "41 Boundary Rd", "93 Boswell Terrace", "4/100 Lockrose St", "32 Williams Ave", "27 scribbly gum st sunnybank hills"};
foreach (string line in linesA)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",words.Skip(3)));
}
```

Comment: How would i print these results to a new file? Keeping all blank lines etc

Comment: No problem @DillonMunien ! For printing to a file, you can look around on SO to do that, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7306243/1685167)'s an example. Just put the foreach inside of the `using StreamWriter` block (where sw.WriteLine()) is, and instead of `Console.WriteLine()`, use `sw.WriteLine()`

Comment: Thanks i got it working :), also if i wanted to do the opposite and remove everything after the 3 words how would i do that?

Comment: Replace Skip() with Take() ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is regular expression way:

```
string[] linesA = new string[5] { "41 Boundary Rd", "93 Boswell Terrace", "4/100 Lockrose St", "32 Williams Ave", "27 scribbly gum st sunnybank hills" };
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* *");
foreach (string s in linesA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(s, ""));
}
```

`[^ ]` match any character except space.