# How can I save my textbox text in a file after previously saved text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two textbox when I press a button textbox text save in a file, but when I again enter new text it is replace the previously saved text.
My code:

```
using (StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter("E:\\win part\\Discrete Mathematics\\userrequest.txt"))
{               
  strw.Write(nametextBox.Text+"\t");
  strw.WriteLine(passwordtextBox.Text);
  strw.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Yor request has been submitted successfully.", "Sucess", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

I want to save this new text after previously saved text.
please help me to solve this.

Comment: did you google ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter

Comment: You could take a look at [StreamWriter (String, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx). Setting the bool to true tells it to append to the file rather than overwrite. In your case it will be `using (StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter("E:\\win part\\Discrete Mathematics\\userrequest.txt", true))`

Comment: Search for "append"

Comment: Would `File.AppendAllText("E:\\win part\\Discrete Mathematics\\userrequest.txt", nametextBox.Text + "\t" + passwordtextBox.Text);` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam B is correct, set 'append' parameter to true for the streamWrite constructor:

```
using (StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter("E:\\win part\\Discrete Mathematics\\userrequest.txt",true))
```

...

Comment: Thanks joe wu, Adam B, Keyur PATEL and Enigmativity to solve my problem, thank you very much.