# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.' Error in SetOut

Tags: c#, streamwriter, console.setout

I'm writing a program that can view all files inside a folder then write the console output to a new txt file but when I run the program after writing 1 line, it produces an error saying

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

Here is the code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CSA FIles(test)\", "*.*", 
                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            if (File.GetLastWriteTime(file)
                < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
            {

               Console.WriteLine(file);


                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\for checking\sample.txt"))
                 {
                     Console.SetOut(writer);
                     Act();
                 }
                 void Act()
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(file);
                 }`
```

Comment: You are setting the console output to a stream, then closing that stream without setting it back to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ron says in his comment, the `StreamWriter` object is being disposed while still being used by `Console`. Best to reinstate the original stream before your `StreamWriter` is disposed.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\for checking\sample.txt"))
{
    var originalStream = Console.Out;
    Console.SetOut(writer);
    Act();
    Console.SetOut(originalStream);
} //writer object is disposed here
```

Microsoft provide an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).

Comment: Hi! It fixed the error but why is it that the text file has only 1 line written?

Comment: The file is opened (and closed) each time around the loop. The file is cleared when its opened this way. Either alter the parameters to StreamWriter to append to an exiting file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter) SO post) or put the using statement outside of the loop to open the file only once