# How to insert lines into the middle of a text file?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a text file in which I need to add some lines after a particular line is encountered.

I have tried making an stream object and then reading from the file until I get the search text and then writing to the same stream by setting its cursor position, but it does not work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Show your code, and we will try to help. If you just want to know how to write to a text file, you should try google or even searching this site. This has been documented a million times over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a text file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919552/how-to-write-a-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: do you need to replace the text that's already in the file, or just insert some new text in the middle of it?

Comment: @JohnFx: I do know how to read  and write to file

Comment: Are you trying to insert a line in the middle of a file?

Comment: Yes; and i dont want to read whole file into string array and then save it back as it would not allow me to "insert" a new line (as no. of lines will then exceed the index as a result of adding new line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's how you can append some text in the middle of the file:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sr = new StreamReader("inputFileName"))
{
    string line;
    do
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    } while (!line.Contains("<Sim Properties>"));

    sb.Append(myText);
    sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
}

using (var sr = new StreamWriter("outputFileName"))
{
    sr.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

this will insert `myText` **after** the line that contains `<Sim Properties>`.

Answer (score 0):

following code example demonstrates the use of the WriteAllLines method to write text to a file. In this example a file is created, if it doesn't already exist, and text is added to it.

```
   using System;
    using System.IO;
    class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

            // This text is added only once to the file. 
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to. 
                string[] createText = { "Hello", "And", "Welcome" };
                File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
            }

            // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
            // if it is not deleted. 
            string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

            // Open the file to read from. 
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            foreach (string s in readText)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually want to append the lines in middle of the file depending on whether the line "<Sim Properties>" is present in the file and its line number

Comment: thanks for your input, but  need to put a new line into the file whenever "<Sim Properties>" is encountered in the file :)